# How do I batch upsert data into Google Cloud Spanner using the Python client library?

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-spanner

I would like to upsert the contents of a pandas dataframe into a table in a Google Cloud Spanner database. The documentation [here](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/spanner/batch-usage.html) recommends using the `insert_or_update()` method of the batch object.

If the batch object is created by running this

```
from google.cloud import spanner_v1
client = spanner_v1.Client()
batch = client.batch()
```

Then this object does not have that method available. Running `dir(client)` gives me these results

```
['SCOPE', 
'_SET_PROJECT', 
'__class__', 
'__delattr__', 
'__dict__', 
'__dir__', 
'__doc__', 
'__eq__', 
'__format__', 
'__ge__', 
'__getattribute__', 
'__getstate__', 
'__gt__', 
'__hash__', 
'__init__', 
'__init_subclass__', 
'__le__', 
'__lt__', 
'__module__', 
'__ne__', 
'__new__', 
'__reduce__', 
'__reduce_ex__', 
'__repr__', 
'__setattr__', 
'__sizeof__', 
'__str__', 
'__subclasshook__', 
'__weakref__', 
'_credentials', 
'_database_admin_api', 
'_determine_default', 
'_http', 
'_http_internal', 
'_instance_admin_api', 
'_item_to_instance', 
'copy', 
'credentials', 
'database_admin_api', 
'from_service_account_json', 
'instance', 
'instance_admin_api', 
'list_instance_configs', 
'list_instances', 
'project', 
'project_name', 
'user_agent']
```

How do I do batch upsert in Spanner?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The snippets has an example of batch insert. I checked that the batch object created in the snippet also has an insert_or_update field.

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/spanner/cloud-client/snippets.py#L72

['**class**', '**delattr**', '**dict**', '**doc**', '**enter**', '**exit**', '**format**', '**getattribute**', '**hash**', '**init**', '**module**', '**new**', '**reduce**', '**reduce_ex**', '**repr**', '**setattr**', '**sizeof**', '**str**', '**subclasshook**', '**weakref**', '_check_state', '_mutations', '_session', 'commit', 'committed', 'delete', 'insert', 'insert_or_update', 'replace', 'update']

Can you try that out?

Comment: Thanks Nithin. I see the documentation has now also been updated to reflect the correct method to access that upsert method. Cheers,

Comment: Repository has been moved, new location seems to be somwhere near https://github.com/googleapis/python-spanner/tree/main/samples/samples but can't find insert_or_update ...

Answer (score 3):

If you have a pandas dataframe, here a random 5 x 3 with columns a,b,c, you can transform the dataframe to column names and the rows and batch insert.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(low=0, high=10, size=(5, 3)),
                  columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
```

You can insert this into Google Cloud Spanner by extracting the columns and values from `df` and batch inserting.

```
from google.cloud import spanner

spanner_client = spanner.Client()
instance = spanner_client.instance(instance_id)
database = instance.database(database_id)

columns = df.columns
values = df.values.tolist()

with database.batch() as batch:
    batch.insert(
        table='table',
        columns=columns
        values=values
    )
```